# Haskell error using sum $ filter 'function' $ [1,2..999]

Tags: haskell

I am trying to figure out multiple Haskell errors I am getting in the following code. Here is my code for Euler problem #1:

```
module Lib
    ( euler1
    ) where

modTest x = mod 3 x == 0 || mod 5 x == 0

euler1 :: IO ()
euler1 = do
  let b = sum $ filter modTest $ [1,2..999]
  putStrLn $ "result: " ++ b
```

And I am getting the following three errors:

```
/home/kuwze/src/haskell/euler-hs/src/Lib.hs:9:11: error:
    • No instance for (Num [Char]) arising from a use of ‘sum’
    • In the expression: sum $ filter modTest $ [1, 2 .. 999]
      In an equation for ‘b’: b = sum $ filter modTest $ [1, 2 .. 999]
      In the expression:
        do { let b = sum $ filter modTest $ ...;
             putStrLn $ "result: " ++ b }

/home/kuwze/src/haskell/euler-hs/src/Lib.hs:9:24: error:
    • No instance for (Integral [Char]) arising from a use of ‘modTest’
    • In the first argument of ‘filter’, namely ‘modTest’
      In the expression: filter modTest
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘filter modTest $ [1, 2 .. 999]’

/home/kuwze/src/haskell/euler-hs/src/Lib.hs:9:34: error:
    • No instance for (Enum [Char])
        arising from the arithmetic sequence ‘1, 2 .. 999’
    • In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘[1, 2 .. 999]’
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘filter modTest $ [1, 2 .. 999]’
      In the expression: sum $ filter modTest $ [1, 2 .. 999] Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I know this is a simple problem but I would really appreciate any help. Thank you so much.

Comment: change to `++ show b`.  You need to convert a Num type to String.  You can also write `[1..999]`.  However, your `mod` test is not correct, swap the arguments otherwise you're just filtering numbers 1,3 and 5.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**tl;dr**: Use `show b` when you print it.

---

Unfortunately, the error here isn't too great. I'll explain where it's coming from though.

```
module Lib
    ( euler1
    ) where

modTest x = mod 3 x == 0 || mod 5 x == 0

euler1 :: IO ()
euler1 = do
  let b = sum $ filter modTest $ [1,2..999]
  putStrLn $ "result: " ++ b
```

Haskell sees your `let b = ...` line and notices that, whatever `b` is, it has to be of some numerical, integral type. That's all fine; you want that. But then you do `"result: " ++ b` and Haskell sees that `b` simply must be a string. So it tries to rationalize this: Is a string a numerical type? The answer is no (unless you defined a really strange instance), and that's why you get the error that `Num [Char]` (or equivalently `Num String`) doesn't work. You simply need to tell Haskell to `show` your numerical value to convert it to a string.

```
putStrLn $ "result: " ++ show b
```

In the future, if you get errors that seem confusing (for instance, the errors you got here were giving you line numbers that were not helpful), try using explicit type signatures. For instance, if you want `b` to be an integer but you're getting errors, try

```
let b = (sum $ filter modTest $ [1,2..999]) :: Int
```

Then you should get a more accurate error message, since Haskell understands more of what you intended. When you've fixed the problem, you can remove the inline type annotations if they're cluttering up the code, but they're very helpful for debugging.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the error message is just saying there *isn't* a `Num` instance for `[Char]`, not that there *cannot* be one.

Comment: Adding a type signature for `modTest` would also help. `modTest :: Int -> Bool` would be sufficient to infer the type `Int` for `b`.

Comment: Yes, this is one of the reasons it is good practice to give types to at least your top-level functions: you get better compiler errors if you tell the compiler what you meant, rather than making it guess which part of your program is wrong when it finds an inconsistency.